# Read and write xml file using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm newbie to Nokogiri ruby gem. I'm wondering how to read and write back to an xml file. The requirement is that I parse xml file, make some changes, and save it.

```
f = File.open("elevate.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
query = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "query", xml
query["text"] = "bank"
query.parent = xml.root

f.close
```

This above code doesn't make any changes to that file at all. Do I have to create new file in order to save it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the XML text of your document as a String using `xml.to_xml` and then write this to a file in the usual way.

Comment: I suppose nokogiri could handle that automatically. Alright, that's maybe the only way to do it.

Comment: Details would be more helpful, but it is nice to know the .to_xml.  Since Nokogiri seems to be appending to my file instead of replacing target as I'd expect.

Comment: @Drew what code are you using that results in an append rather than a replace?

Comment: The append is due to using File.open('path','r+').
I found I had to open the file File.open('path','r'), then to modify the file I did a separate File.open('path','w').
I couldn't find a way to use the same file pointer to do both reading and writing (r+ just appends)